# create array they having same value for different label

Tags: php, arrays

I create form in drupal to find a area.in which we have same value for differet key.when we write following array they will take only last key of same value like for family law it takes only Restraining Orders so how we can create array they will take same value for different label.

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_state) 
{
$area_one=array(
'Bankruptcy' =>'Bankruptcy',
'Criminal Defense' =>'Criminal Defense',
'Criminal Defense' =>'Driving Under Influence (of Drugs and or Alcohol)',
'Expungement' =>'Expungement',
'Family Law' =>'Family Law',
'Family Law' =>'Alimony',
'Family Law'=>'Child Custody',
'Family Law' =>'Child Visitation',
'Family Law' =>'Divorce',
'Family Law'=>'Restraining Orders',
'Employment' =>'Employment',
'Immigration'=>'Immigration',
'Immigration'=>'Deportation Defense',
'Personal Injury' =>'Personal Injury',
'Real Estate' =>'Real Estate',
'Taxation' =>'Taxation',
'Workers’ Compensation Applicant'=>'Workers’ Compensation',
'Wills, Trusts & Probate' =>'Wills, Trusts & Probate',
 ); 

$a=array_search('Family Law', array_reverse($area_one));
$form['Lawyername'] = array(
'#title' => t('Select Practice Areas'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => $a,
'#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['Location'] = array(
'#title' => t('California County'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#autocomplete_path' => 'form_test-autocomplete-engine',
'#required' => TRUE,
);

 $form['submit'] = array(
 '#value' => 'Submit',
 '#type' => 'submit',
 );
 return $form;
 }
```

Comment: Reword your question so people can actually understand it

Answer (score 1):

You could [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/array_reverse) the array, and then use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) to retrieve the key, eg:

```
echo array_search('Family Law', array_reverse($area_one)); // 'Restraining Orders'
```

#### [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cLEyCa)

Comment: I did this but page disappear.please see above code.